# How to get payment method in an observer in Magento?

Tags: magento, paypal, observer-pattern

I have an observer that handles the event: sales_payment_invoice_pay (or something like that).

What I'm trying to do is to send an invoice if the payment method is PayPal.

Everything is ok in version 1.4~ by doing $observer->getEvent()->getOrder()->getPayment->getMethodInstance().

In version 1.5+ however I can't seem to find any solutions.
I also tried with getData() but without any results.

Any help is appreciated. thanks

Calling me super desperate for an answer would be an understatement.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the only data passed in to the `sales_order_invoice_pay` event is `$this`, which will be the `sales/order_invoice` model. I found this by searching through the Magneto core code, it's fired off in Invoice.php like so:

```
Mage::dispatchEvent('sales_order_invoice_pay', array($this->_eventObject=>$this));
```

Looking at a similar event (`sales_order_invoice_register`) which has an observer in the core (of Enterprise, at least - `increaseOrderGiftCardInvoicedAmount()` in GiftCardAccount) you can access the Invoice object like this in your Observer method:

```
$invoice = $observer->getEvent()->getInvoice();
```

The invoice is all you will be able to get though, since it's the only thing passed to the Observers by `dispatchEvent()`. You cannot directly access the order, like you are trying to do.

Looking at the Invoice model, however, it appears to have a nice `getOrder` method, which should do the trick. I haven't tested it, but try this:

```
$observer->getEvent()->getInvoice()->getOrder()->getPayment->getMethodInstance();
```

Cheers and good luck!

Comment: It isn't working unfortunately. That is how I tried it as well.

Comment: Sorry it's not working yet - it's time to bust out `Mage::log()` then I guess. Make sure your Observer is firing first (nothing will work if your event isn't being triggered properly!). Then perhaps dump what `$observer->getEvent()->getInvoice()` returns, to make sure it's an Invoice. Keep working your way up that call chain until you get to `getMethodInstance`. There are lots of good articles on the web about debugging Magento, good luck.

Answer (score 2):

i can get the payment method code using this

```
$observer->getEvent()->getInvoice()->getOrder()->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getCode()
```

Answer (score 0):

user this code:$order->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getCode() ;